# Conservation of velocity flux in fluid mechanics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, flow

I am currently working through the book *Vorticity and Incompressible Flow* by Majda and Bertozzi. They define the velocity flux as $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}udx$, where $u = u(t,x)$ is some smooth vector field satisfying the (incompressible) Euler equations. They claim, that the velocity flux is a conserved quantity, given that $u$ vanishes rapidly as $|x|\rightarrow\infty$. Like usual they rewrite the integral by using the Euler equations, where $p$ denotes the pressure:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}u^idx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\partial_t u^idx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}-u\cdot\nabla u^idx - \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\partial_i pdx$$
I understand, why $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}-u\cdot\nabla u^idx$ vanishes. Unfortunately it is unclear to me, why the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\partial_i pdx$ vanishes as well.

I am well aware that one can use a Calderon-Zygmund like operator to regain the pressure $p$ from $u$, but 1)this looks like an overkill and 2)I am sure there is an elementary argument. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's just a boundary term. Just as for the previous term, you need to assume that $p$ decays faster than $r^{-2}$ for it to be zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot @LPZ.